# How to setup Automount/Autofs

Tags: installation, automount, nfs

I've followed the ubuntu help docs for [setting up NFSv4 on a server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#NFSv4%20server) running Ubuntu 10.4LTS and now I'm trying to get Autofs  (on ubuntu 10.10) to mount the exports, following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs). So far it doesn't work.

Where the docs say `server   -fstype=nfs4   server:/` I'm supposed to replace 'server' with my server's hostname right? If yes, should that be `server-foo` or `server-foo.local`?

```
# Sample /etc/auto.master file
#  --- comments snipped --8<--
+auto.master            # pre-existing
/nfs   /etc/auto.nfs    # added by me
```

.

```
# manually created /etc/auto.nfs
ubuntu-server.local   -fstype=nfs4   ubuntu-server.local:/
```

`ls /nfs/ubuntu-server /nfs/ubuntu-server.local` shows nothing. What's the next troubleshooting step?

---

*[update 2011-feb-12]* I followed the procedure outlined at [Which to use NFS or Samba?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba/7124#7124). I've now verified that my server export is working because I can mount the nfs shares via `/etc/fstab`. Here is my config, server side:

```
/home/matt      192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/home/shared    192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

And in client `/etc/fstab`:

```
ubuntu-server:/home/matt  /nfs/matt  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
ubuntu-server:/home/shared  /nfs/shared  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

followed by `sudo mount /nfs/shared`. 
(I also needed to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` so the server name would resolve to ip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server name is ubuntu-server, `/nfs/tutu` where to mount the nfs share, then in `/etc/auto.nfs`:

```
tutu -fstype=nfs4 ubuntu-server:/
```

and then run:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d autofs restart

ls /nfs/tutu
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. It did not lead to a solution for me, but I think I may have deeper network issues at play, for instance `ping ubuntu-server` does not resolve, I have to use ip.

Comment: this finally works for me, though I followed a long and circuitous route to get here, so the solution may be incomplete. Part of it least involved hard coding the server ip into /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

Here's my auto.master file for reference :

/etc/auto.master

```
+auto.master
/smb /etc/auto.smb uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=300 --ghost
```

For my samba share, that's all I need to do to see my shares listed :

```
scaine@GroovyTosh:~$ ls /smb/core
Archive  Backups  Data  Live
```

Due to a bug in smbclient, I have to specify the UID and GID.  The timeout is how long before autofs unmounts an unused share and the ghost option keeps previously created folders in place inside /smb even when the share is not available.

I can also browse my /smb by IP address (e.g. `ls /smb/192.168.1.10`).

In your case, you might want to try the /net option, instead of manually specifying your exports.  So your auto.master would simply be :

```
+auto.master
/net /etc/auto.net --timeout=300 --ghost
```

Then after a `sudo service autofs restart`, try `ls /net`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The `/net` line does nothing for me, however `/smb` does get me partway: after adding that and restarting autofs`ls /smb/192.168.1.123` shows the share names I expect, I just can't open any of them.

Comment: Well that's weird.  Your server must be configured for Samba then, as well as the NFS config you're trying to get working.  Seeing the shares is a success - you just need to specify the correct `/etc/auto.smb.192.168.1.123` file now to pass credentials to the samba server.