Trying to mount a shared folder in ubuntu
I'm having problems trying to get my NAS to work on my Plex server.
I'm trying to mount the shared folder in the server but it gives me the error
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
I think i'm doing everything OK. The commands I ran were
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.X.X:/volume1/shared /root/Tuga

I think its something to do with permissions and user permissions but I do not know how to give permissions in my Synology NAS to my server user.

Why are you mounting inside the /root/ directory? Why not in some more traditional location, e.g. /mnt/ or something? I am not especially well informed around the /root/ dir, but I would not be surprised if it would impose special circumstances regarding permissions. Theoretically you should not be operating regular daily tasks in there.

The first time I tryed i did outside of the root dir but had the same error

will this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/884389/auto-mount-nfs-via-autonfs

I hate to ask this, but did you make sure that NFS support is enabled on your NAS?  https://kb.synology.com/en-br/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

I have the NFS service activated and the max NFS is NFSv4.1

You may get some additional diagnostic information by adding verbosity (-vvv) to your mount command. As well, the output of showmount -e 192.168.X.X can sometimes be helpful. Is the share exported with no_root_squash on the server?

When i do the showmount -e 192.168.X.X it gives me back the:
Export list for 192.168.X.X:
/volume1/shared 192.168.X.0/24

Mount it to your user directory so you have correct permissions.
For example, create a directory mkdir -p ~/mnt/Tuga
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.X.X:/volume1/shared ~/mnt/Tuga

It gives me the exact same error. can it be the permitions to access the shared folder of the NAS ? how can i give acess to ubuntu user in the NAS ?

So the NFS server is define in your /etc/exports file.  Can you post the contents of that?  You are trying to play videos in Plex from your NFS server?
