# How to setup a Shared Folder on Mythbuntu without using SAMBA?

Tags: shared-folders

We don't have Windows at home, so don't use SAMBA.  Can NFS be used natively between Ubuntu and Mythbuntu machines?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes. Mythbuntu *is* Ubuntu.

Anything you can install on Ubuntu you can install on Mythbuntu, it's just a respin. So just install the nfs client/server in the arrangement you need.

- [The full guide on NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) is very thorough. I'd argue it's too thorough for most people in closed networks because you really don't have to bother with the security if you trust every machine on the network.
- [My own cut-down guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/7124/449) should let you get up and running with minimal reading.