# How to configure a network in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, lan

I have 5 desktops, all running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

All are connecting to the Internet through the LAN (using a dlink switch),
I want to see all of them in the network and sharing, and also I want to make a dedicated folder on a desktop to share files on other desktops.

I installed Samba and i also give permission to a folder as share with everyone, but it still isn't visible on other desktops :(

Please help me in making a LAN connection for sharing, Internet is working fine on all pc's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"samba" is for connecting Windows machines with Linux machines. It can be used for Linuxes too but there are better methods.

If all your systems are Linux based please use "nfs" (where 1 machine acts as the server and the others as clients). You can then mount discs from the other machines onto any of the other machines in exact the same fashion as you would use local harddisks.

---

- [Quickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)
- [Which to use NFS or Samba?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba)
- [ubuntuforums howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=249889)