# File Transfer over Wifi

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have two Laptops, Samsung Notebook (32bit System) and Dell (64bit system) both running Ubuntu 14.04. I have connected a Dlink USB 3G modem to Samsung Notebook and set up a WiFi Hotspot on it. So I am currently using the internet on all other devices in my home using this WiFi Network.

Can I share the files on one laptop with other one over this WiFi network? If yes, how should I configure both computers?

Also if it is not possible how can I share files over internet, so that I can access those from my other laptop and also from any other computer(outside my network, say from computer in my college) over internet? (I don't want to setup a FTP server).

I tried Bit-torrent Sync but for different locations I have to set different passwords.

Also how can set my Mobile Broadband connection (3G using USB Dlink Modem) to redial automatically? because sometimes it gets disconneted automatically.. The inbuilt option in Ubuntu's Default connection manager works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work especially when modem gets disconnected due to removal of USB cable or due to spike in electrical wires when speed of an electrical fan is changed from the Regulator.
The connection will dial itself automatically when the option "Enable Mobile Broadband" is selected, but when the connection gets disconnected due to reasons stated above, the "Enable Mobile Broadband" option get unchecked and hence the connection will not be able to dial itself automatically.

[image: Screenshot showing Connection Manager Options]

Please give in detail instructions.

Comment: Why don't you try mega for internet sync? https://mega.nz/ or free file sync if you don't want your files on the cloud http://www.freefilesync.org/

Comment: I mean what are advantages of using Samba over NFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, how to transfer files over the same WiFi network, you can use Samba. You just need to configure a Samba shared folder in one computer and access it on the other.

Directly for nautilus (the file manager), right click on the folder you want to share, click on **[local network share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcjBX.png)**. A [new window will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As66x.png), if you click on **Share this folder** a poupup will appear asking you to install some components. Accept and wait for the installation. 
When the installation finishes tick the options you think are appropiate for you. When only I have access to the network and I've not sensitive data in the folder (or I mount there other folders or put symbolic link to only the files I need) I tick all of them. *You can leave blank the **Comment** field*.

On the other PC (or any device, such as smartphones), open *nautilus* and click on **Browse Network** and click on the hostname of the other PC and after on the share name you set in the other PC.

You can also click on **Connect to Server** and in the **Server Address** filed type *smb://other_pc_ip/folderName* .

Comment: Do I need to install Samba to share files from one Ubuntu system to anoher? isn't it required where I want to share files between a Windows system and Ubuntu System?

Comment: I mean what are advantages of using Samba over NFS?

Comment: @AniruddhaArondekar [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/7124/484853) there is a good explanation of the differences between Samba and NFS. In few words Samba is slower but easyer to configure, doesn't require other software in the client and its shares are readable from Windows and Android too.